# Error Forge Viewer Integration with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I followed a GitHub code (https://github.com/adamenagy/sharepointonline-integration) and an Autodesk blog (https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/sharepoint-online-integration).

I successfully created a SharePoint App and added it to my site pages, but ForgeViewer is not getting a load.

Please see the attached image; I also run a local gulp serve. Please take a look at the attached image.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Ravi[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRRbW.png)

I follow all the instructions in the above shared GitHub Read—me and Autodesk blog.

Even run a local gulp serve.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `CLIENT_ID`/`CLIENT_SECRET` needed to be set in the [ViewerWebpartWebPart.ts](https://github.com/adamenagy/sharepointonline-integration/blob/pagemonitor/src/webparts/viewerWebpart/ViewerWebpartWebPart.ts) file.
Without that there was no **access token** used in the requests and that resulted in the confusing error message.